# Eclipse EASE Javascript - HelloWorld

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, plugins

Hi I'm planning to create a scripting program to scan my Eclipse Java Elements - Class/Interfaces and need to generate some report before compiling. While searching in web, I found this new Eclipse EASE concepts. However, I've downloaded required plugins in Eclipse.

Still I'm not able to run a sample Hello World Application program.

I created new file - "hello.js" which simply has only one statement
print("Hello World")

When i tried to Run As - EASE scripts , i'm getting the below error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.eclipse.ease.lang.javascript.JavaScriptCodeFactory.getPreExecutionCode(Lorg/eclipse/ease/modules/IEnvironment;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.eclipse.ease.lang.javascript.JavaScriptCodeFactory.buildMethodBody(JavaScriptCodeFactory.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.ease.lang.javascript.JavaScriptCodeFactory.createFunctionWrapper(JavaScriptCodeFactory.java:243)
    at org.eclipse.ease.AbstractCodeFactory.createWrapper(AbstractCodeFactory.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.ease.lang.javascript.JavaScriptCodeFactory.createWrapper(JavaScriptCodeFactory.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.ease.modules.EnvironmentModule.createWrappers(EnvironmentModule.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ease.modules.EnvironmentModule.wrap(EnvironmentModule.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.ease.modules.EnvironmentModule.bootstrap(EnvironmentModule.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callProp0(OptRuntime.java:85)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c_17._c_script_0(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c_17.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c_17.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.gen.c_17.exec(Unknown Source)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.evaluateReader(Context.java:1110)
    at org.eclipse.ease.lang.javascript.rhino.RhinoScriptEngine.internalExecute(RhinoScriptEngine.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.ease.lang.javascript.rhino.RhinoScriptEngine.execute(RhinoScriptEngine.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.ease.AbstractScriptEngine.inject(AbstractScriptEngine.java:227)
    at org.eclipse.ease.AbstractScriptEngine.run(AbstractScriptEngine.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
org.eclipse.ease.ScriptExecutionException: ReferenceError: "print" is not defined.
    at hello.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `EASE Core` and `EASE Javascript Support (Incubation)` installed from the update site http://download.eclipse.org/ease/update/release.

[image: Install EASE Core and EASE Javascript Support (Incubation)]

Then make sure you have the `Environment` module loaded, which provides the `print()` method.
Usually this module should be loaded automatically but you can also do it manually:

```
new Packages.org.eclipse.ease.modules.EnvironmentModule().loadModule("/System/Environment", false);

print("hello, world")
```